# Angular 2: emit from child component directly to the parent component's script file

Tags: templates, angular, components, parent-child, emit

I have a nested component that I wish to emit some data directly to the parents typescript file without going through the template. **I can't use** `<child (childEvent)="parentFunc()"></child>`

Is this possible? If so, how?

This is the current state of things.

**parent.component.html** (The element **must** be this)

```
<child #child> </child>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('child') public child;

public doSomething() {
  this.child.work();
}

public doThisWhenChildEmits(someData) {
  //?????How do I call this function from child without going through the DOM
  alert(It worked)
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Output() private childEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()
...
public work() {
   // does some work that changes the child's template
}

public clickToSendBack(){
   // click event that sends back to parent.component directly????
   this.childEvent.emit(someData);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use `@Output` you could use `Subject` instead:

Your parent would subscribe to changes. In your parent, declare a Subject in component and in the constructor subscribe to changes:

```
public static changesMade: Subject<any> = new Subject();

//inside constructor the following
ParentComponent.changesMade.subscribe(res => {
  //call your method here, with the res (someData) you receive from child
  this.doThisWhenChildEmits(res);
});
```

and in your child:

```
public clickToSendBack(){
   // send the data to parent
   ParentComponent.changesMade.next(someData)
}
```

Let me know if this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you. I think your answer will work, I want to give it a couple days before I commit to it and select yours as the best answer.

Comment: Sure thing, I understand! :)